# soci: return primary key after "insert into"

Tags: c++, sql, soci

Im using soci with C++ to access my database. Is it possible to modify the following expression in a way to get the new primary key that was given to the row which is added by that expression?

```
 *dbSession << "insert into myTable(myRow) values (:myVal)", soci::use(myVal);
```

e.g.

```
 long newID = *dbSession << "insert into myTable(myRow) values (:myVal)", soci::use(myVal);
```

So that I can continue my work by using newID? id is in this case the primary key (bigserial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL you can use `RETURNING` to get the generated ID.
Like: `INSERT INTO tbloCustomer (Name) VALUES ('Goofy') RETURNING ID;`
(If your Primary Key is called ID ;)

Comment: I dont know how to formulate this with soci. On this page: http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/3.2/exchange.html are some examples but without using "returning"

Comment: Sorry seems like `RETURNING` only works with PostgreSQL since it's a extension..
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-insert.html

Comment: luckily im using postgres and "[...] returning id", soci::into(id); works like a charm, thx!